# PHP & JavaScript - Redirecting to a dynamic URL

Tags: php, javascript

Just a quick question.

At the moment I have a login script that re-directs to dashboard.php where the user can click a button to retrieve Google Analytics stats for the pre-selected current month and year.

The url for May 2011 is: `dashboard.php?month=May&year=2011&submit=Get+Statistics!`

So what I am trying to do is have the stats load with the page instead of having to click the button.

The only way I can think to do this is by changing the following line in my login script:

```
// redirect to secure page
document.location='dashboard.php';
```

to something like:

```
// redirect to secure page
document.location='dashboard.php' + <?php echo ?month=currentMonth&year=currentYear&submit=Get+Statistics! ?>';
```

with the month and year variables set as follows:
    $currentMonth = date('F');
    $currentYear = date('Y');

But this doesn't work, it just goes to dashboard.php as normal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the single quote in front of the second string:

```
document.location='dashboard.php' + '<?php echo "?month=currentMonth&year=currentYear&submit=Get+Statistics!" ?>';
```

should work in a PHP file.

Comment: ah, thanks, trouble with that is I am literally being redirected to `dashboard.php<?php echo "?month=currentMonth&year=currentYear&submit=Get+Statistics!" ?>`, will see if I can mess around with it to get it working in the meantime.

Comment: Is this JavaScript in a PHP file? If not, the PHP statement won't execute. I.e, the file that it's in must end in .php, and be on a server (locally using XAMPP/MAMP etc or remotely).

Comment: I have login.php which includes login.js which in turn has this re-direct code in it.

Comment: I think you'll need to put that JS inline within login.php or it won't work.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a bash, it's not too bad, was just trying not to clutter up the page with html, php and js! Let you know in two minutes if this works...

Comment: If you want to reduce clutter, you could put your JavaScript into an external PHP file (e.g., js.php), then use `<?php include('js.php'); ?>` in login.php.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I've verified that this works using the script as an include or inline with login.php. If it works for you, do you mind marking this answer as accepted? If it doesn't, perhaps some other devilment is at work :)

Comment: Hi g_thom, apologies for the delay, my host was down so I was just waiting to get ftp access back. Just updated and it does indeed work, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is when you wrote your post, but your echo is missing quotes :

Try this :

```
document.location='dashboard.php' + <?php echo "?month=currentMonth&year=currentYear&submit=Get+Statistics!"; ?>';
```

Comment: thanks, I tried `document.location='dashboard.php' + <?php echo "?month=$currentMonth&year=$currentYear&submit=Get+Statistics!"; ?>;` but no joy I'm afraid.

It might be an issue but the js is in an external file which is included after the php variables are set so I don't think that should break it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are in the same scope, you can get the variables in any part of the code:

```
// redirect to secure page
document.location='dashboard.php' + <?= "?month=$currentMonth&year=$currentYear&submit=Get+Statistics!"; ?>';
```

Comment: Thanks, looks the same as what I tried except for the `<?=`, is that a typo or just something I've not seen before? I tried it anyway and it kills the page!

Comment: It's called short open tag, and it's not a good programming style. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag I think I'm too used to codegolfing :P

Comment: cool, I knew you could do <? but never seen <?= . I used to use <? but turns out it can cause problems depending on the server as some can't process it so I always use the 'long' version now!